# Java: Object of abstract class

Tags: java, oop, object, abstract-class

I got confused about the code stated below, where `Player` is an `abstract` class:

```
private void cbxTeamAItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                          
        if (evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            Player p = (Player) evt.getItem();
            if(P.getTipo().contains("Defense")){
                lblDefense1.setText("Skill:");
            }
        }
}
```

If in Java I **can not** create an `Object` of an `abstract` class, why is this working?

Isn't this line a instance of `Player` ?

```
Player p = (Player) evt.getItem();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing variable with instance. `p` is a Player variable, and `evt.getItem()` returns a **concrete instance** of a type that extends Player (or implements Player if Player were an interface). What exact sub-type of Player isn't important since all that you need to know is that it adhere's to the Player abstract class contract and thus has all the necessary Player behaviors.

Comment: Ow! Got it! It would be the same of Player P = new Defense()? (in my case Defense extends Player)

Comment: @Mucida: yes, similar to that.

Comment: But why should I cast it to (Player) and not just this: Player p = evt.getItem()?

Comment: @Mucida: because `evt.getItem()` is likely declared to return `Object` type.

Answer (score 3):

The variable p holds a reference to an instance of a subclass of the abstract class Player. Since the Player is an abstract class, no instance of it can be created. However, instances of the subclass of the abstract Player class can still be assigned to the variable p. See https://www.computingnotes.net/java/abstract-class-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can have objects that have an abstract class as their type even though you can't directly construct abstract classes. `evt.getItem()` has a specific, non-abstract type that it returns under the hood, and that type implements `Player` with some specific code. If, someday, they wanted to change the name of that class, they could, and it wouldn't affect this code as long as it continued to implement all the methods in `Player`. Basically, this abstracts the specifics of that object away from you and only assures you that somewhere, someone implemented all the methods that a `Player` ought to have in the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can not create instance of `abstract` class but you can up cast child to it's parent. In your case `evt.getItem()` is returning the `child` (*i.e.* `TennisPlayer`) and you are casting it to super class `Player` which is valid.

Consider following example,

```
class Mango extends Fruit {}

abstract class Fruit {}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mango mango = new Mango();
        //Note that mango is also fruit
        Fruit fruit = (Fruit) mango;
    }

}
```

Note it is valid to up cast child to it's parent because (*i.e.*) every `Mango` is *surely* a `Fruit`.

Comment: Humm. That is why the cast (Player) evt.getItem() could "find" the subclass Defense?